# Como receber uma matriz de caracteres em C com for?

Tags: c, matriz, caracteres

Considerando MxN como 2x2, preciso receber em cada posicao do MxN um caracter.

por exemplo:

> r d
> g h

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("Digite um caractere para a posicao %d x %d da matriz: ",i,j);
            scanf("%c", &caractere[i][j]);
        }
    }

printf("%c",caractere[0][0]);
printf("%c",caractere[0][1]);
printf("%c",caractere[1][0]);
printf("%c",caractere[1][1]);
```

A questão é:

Se eu coloco para receber dentro dos for's com `scanf("%s", &caractere[i][j]);` fica assim:
(consigo digitar cada letra em cada posição, mas na hora de salvar, ele pega as duas ultimas e sobrescreve as duas primeiras. - tentando digitar tgds, ele salva dsds).

```
Digite um caractere para a posicao 0 x 0 da matriz: t 
Digite um caractere para a posicao 0 x 1 da matriz: g 
Digite um caractere para a posicao 1 x 0 da matriz: d 
Digite um caractere para a posicao 1 x 1 da matriz: s 
dsds
```

Se eu coloco para receber com `scanf("%c", &caractere[i][j]);` fica assim:
(não consigo digitar as duas letras, ele já coloca os dois printf's juntos - conforme abaixo.)

```
Digite um caractere para a posicao 0 x 0 da matriz: Digite um caractere para a posicao 0 x 1 da matriz: re 
Digite um caractere para a posicao 1 x 0 da matriz: Digite um caractere para a posicao 1 x 1 da matriz: e 
e
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo receber uma matriz de caracteres em c?
Seria com 2 for mesmo?
Por que não consigo colocar em cada posição corretamente?

*------------

coloquei desta forma, ele aparentemente pega um a um:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m = 0, n = 0, i, j;
    char caractere[m][n];
    
    m = 2;
    n = 2;
    
    for(i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("Digite um caractere para a posicao %d x %d da matriz: ",i,j);
            scanf(" %c", &caractere[i][j]);
        }
    }
 
    printf("\n%c",caractere[0][0]);
    printf("\t%c",caractere[0][1]);
    printf("\n%c",caractere[1][0]);
    printf("\t%c\n",caractere[1][1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

porém, olha o retorno: (continua, pegando sempre os 2 últimos inseridos.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: faz tempo que eu não brinco com C, mas tente fazer isso no seu scanf `scanf("%c", &(caractere[i][j]));` está certa ao utilizar dois `for` é um for para cada dimensão da array

Comment: como explicação o operador de referência & está sendo aplicado somente à `caractere[i]` e depois ele pega o índice j dentro da referência... por isso sugeri trocar para incluir os parênteses assim & se aplica à `caractere[i][j]`

Comment: Você está digitando um caractere em um ENTER? Se for dessa forma o caractere ENTER está sendo lido pelo segundo scanf. Tente informar `rdgh<ENTER>` ou limpe o buffer de entrada após cada leitura,

Comment: @JMSlasher eu tentei fazer desta forma `scanf("%c", &(caractere[i][j]));`, porém ainda sim, ele lê o scanf duas vezes seguidas, conforme o exemplo que postei na pergunta (imagem).

Comment: @anonimo mesmo sem ler o enter, na questão quando uso o %s, ele duplica as ultimas duas entradas. Não seria por causa do enter.

Comment: Mas se você está lendo caractere então não utilize o formato `%s` que é para ler string. Use o `%c`. Uma outra forma de ler a antrda com cada caractere seguido de um ENTER é consumir este ENTER com um espaço antes do %c: `scanf(" %c", &caractere[i][j]);`.

Comment: Veja teste em: https://ideone.com/7VkVDP

Comment: @anonimo, cara entendi. Fiz exatamente desta forma. Mas, olha o retorno. (irei postar na pergunta, para colocar a imagem)

Comment: Caraca, que burrada a minha. @AnthonyAccioly deu certo. Se quiserem colocar como resposta, para eu aceitar. Tá aí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema do seu código está no seguinte trecho:

```
int m = 0, n = 0, i, j;
char caractere[m][n];
```

Esse código está declarando um VLA (*variable length array*) vazio uma vez que `m` e `n` são iguais a 0.

Se você mudar os valores de `m` e `n` para `2` o seu código deve funcionar; dito isso, se você sabe que a sua matriz é sempre 2X2 é melhor declarar tamanhos fixos:

```
char caractere[2][2];
```

*VLAs* são parte do padrão C99, porém na prática eles não são muito usados por uma série de motivos que fogem ao escopo da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A forma de preencher a matriz são com 2 for's mesmo, essa parte está correta, acontece que do jeito que está seu código ele está lendo um caractere que você digitou e em seguida o próximo scanf vai ler o "enter" que você dá quando termina de digitar. Colocando a função `getchar()` logo depois do scanf você garante que ela irá pegar esse "enter" que está te dando problema. Esta seria a forma mais correta a se fazer, porém também seria possível fazer utilizando o `scanf("%s")`, eu testei na minha máquina o seu código com esse caso e deu certo para qualquer entrada, pode ser uma versão diferente do compilador ou das libs dando respostas diferentes então realmente opte pela primeira alternativa que apresentei.

Comment: Ei @Iagor, coloquei o getchar(). porém, ele ainda imprime somente os dois ultimos, conforme comentário que fiz. Utilizo o DevC++ para compilar. Será que é algum bug dele?